# Spring RequestMapping with custom isLoggedIn parameter

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

I've been searching internet for several hours now, and cannot find a way to add my own variables into request mapping.

We are using a custom user authentication system. And I want to serve 2 different controllers for the same path depending on if the user is authenticated or not. More specifically, I want to create controllers that only mapped to if the user is not authenticated.

How can I achieve something like this: (I want to define `isLoggedIn` myself).

```
public class PageController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/page", isLoggedIn = false)
  @ResponseBody
  String getPage(){
    return "Page content";
  }
}
```

I want request to hit this controller if user is not logged in, and fallback to catch all if user is logged in. I am open to solutions using Interceptors, Custom Annotations, or extending RequestMapping or anything else.

Comment: So you want to have 2 different controllers with the same path?

Comment: Could you just send a HTTP 401 when not logged in instead of changing your request mapping?

Comment: So spring mvc will not allow you to have the same paths in different controllers. It won't even allow parameterized urls that look the same.

Comment: I want request to hit this controller if user is not logged in, and fallback to catch all if user is logged in. @aksappy

Comment: You can do 2 things instead - use the security context inside the same method and check, or use a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to tackle security permissions before even reaching the URL.

Comment: Can you explain what does `fallback to catch all if user is logged in` mean?

Comment: You can create custom annotation like @GetMapping. You can check the implementation in spring.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public @interface CustomGetRequestMapping {

    @AliasFor(value = "value", annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String path();

    boolean isLoggedIn() default false;
}
```

I guess this is not enough because you have to write interceptor and catch the logged in user.